# trying to use a vue-awesome icon but having trouble

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use the regular window-close icon from vue-awesome. I have loaded my vue-awesome via:

```
import 'vue-awesome/icons';
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue';

Vue.component('icon', Icon);
```

Based upon the docs here https://github.com/Justineo/vue-awesome#usage , I am able to load via:

```
<icon name="window-close"></icon>
```

But this defaults to the solid icon. However, rather than using the solid, I'd like to use the regular. It seems based upon their docs it should be:

```
<icon name="regular/window-close"></icon>
```

but this gives me the following error:

[image]

How would I use the regular icon from vue-awesome?

Comment: Can you share `Icon.vue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat we had, it seemed that your `vue-awesome` package is outdated.

You can update the package using

```
npm install vue-awesome --latest
// OR
yarn add vue-awesome@latest
```

Comment: thx - I tried the `import 'vue-awesome/icons/regular'` but it would fail to compile and get the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-awesome/icons/regular'`.  So I'm confused as to what do next. If I cd into node_modules/icons/ - there is no reqular folder. Do I need to install or update this?

Comment: Okay, give me sometime to test out in my test project.

Comment: thx - I know it's something really naive on my part. appreciate the help.

Comment: Okay, this is weird. I reproduced your code exactly and it worked for me. I have this line `import 'vue-awesome/icons'` after `import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon'` Can you try this method? I will update my answer if this works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169904/discussion-between-ru-chern-chong-and-timpone).

Answer (score 0):

Use `:name` to bind attribute , if value is `window-close`

```
  <icon :name="'window-close'"></icon>
```